# Repeat alloc to same pointer - what happens?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

HI all,

What happens if you repeat the following code more than once ?

```
pointer * mypointer = [[object alloc]init];
```

Do you just increase the retain count of that object by one again ?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Most objects do not handle the alloc method, since that is very possibly creating a memory leak.  Perhaps you meant [[ myClass alloc ] init] ?

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't increase the retain count - only the `retain` message does that on an allocated object. Running that exact code more than once would actually error out, since you'd be duplicating the `pointer * mypointer` type declaration. However, if you had (for example):

```
pointer * mypointer = [[object alloc] init];
mypointer = [[object alloc] init];
```

You would have made two instances of `object`, each at its own position in memory, and you would have lost your handle on the first one (since `mypointer` now contains a reference to the second instance of `object`). Effectively, this is a leak.